# Map ZonedDateTime String to LocalDateTime by XML Parser on Fly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, timestamp, zoneddatetime

I have an XML response String as:
`<timestamp ts="2018-12-05T08:00:00+02:00">55.5</timestamp>`

I mapped this with help of `JAXB` and annotations as:

```
public class Timestamp {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ts")
    private String timeStampAsString;
    @XmlValue
    private Double value;
```

and it works as it should, but I would like to automatically parse the `DateTime` from `String`, so my ideal solution should have

```
public class Timestamp {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ts")
    private LocalDateTime timeStampAsLocalDateTime;
    @XmlValue
    private Double value;
```

I know that I can parse String with help of:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(zonedDateTimeAsString).toLocalDateTime();
```

But I'm not sure if there is a way to parse this `on fly`.

Comment: For most purposes a `LocalDateTime` is the poor choice for a timestamp since you need to interpret it in a time zone or at a UTC offset before using it as a point in time, which is error-prone (at best). Please consider an `Instant` or another class that in itself defines a point in time.

Comment: What does “on Fly” mean?

Comment: Your `ts` Strings should be parsed as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `XmlAdapter`.

Create a class that extends `XmlAdapter` which converts `String` to `LocalDateTime`

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(v).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return v.toString();
    }
 }
```

And annotate the field you want converted to LocalDateTime:

```
    @XmlAttribute(name="ts")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime timeStampAsLocalDateTime;
```

(as already mentioned in the comments `LocalDateTime` can be problematic, `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` might be a better fit. This approach will be the same, just replace the classes and parsing logic)